# How do I find the top and left of a button in the Delphi XE2 ribbon control?

Tags: delphi, ribbon

The project I am working on has a demo mode which shows the user some of the features by moving the the mouse with setcursorpos to different controls. The position of the control is needed for the setcursorpos function. How do I find these for the tabs and buttons in a ribbon control?

Comment: You actually need a [CBT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-based_training), dont reinvent the wheel

Comment: I followed Uwe's suggestion and used the following.

var
btnpos:tpoint;
...
btnpos:=RibbonGroup2.ActionControls[0].ClientOrigin;
setcursorpos(btnpos.x,btnpos.y);
.. 

It works perfectly. You do not need to apply clienttoscreen to the tpoint value. If the window is resized until the Ribbon group gets collapsed Clientorigin returns a negative value (-32703 for me) on the X value. If I get a less than zero value, I could maximize the window, ask the user to max the screen or abort the demo. 

Thank you Uwe Raabe and everyone for the help.

Comment: @user539484, the project and demo was too small to warrant a separate CBT solution. Moving the mouse to the button and popping a balloon in the center with information was easier. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK SetCursorPos needs screen related coordinates for the mouse position. Assuming the target control is named Button1 you get the screen coordinates of the top left corner with `Button1.ClientOrigin;`

**Update:** Although not directly asked, it may be not clear how to get hands on the control instance representing the button. Let me take the RibbonDemo from the XE2 samples folder. The Delete button (index 3) on the Clipboard section can be accessed via rgHomeClipboard.ActionControls[3];

Comment: Are ribbon controls windowed?

Comment: @David: Just curious: In Delphi 2009, the `TRibbon` control is implemented entirely in the VCL code; it's not the native Windows control. Has that changed in XE2?

Comment: @Andreas I've no idea. The Windows ribbon is by far the best option but it's not VCL and could be hard to code against. I did not think buttons had postitions like a TControl.

Comment: @David, the controls in the VCL ribbon (which I assumed as XE2 Ribbon Control was mentioned) uses TCustomActionControl descendants, which are itself derived from TGraphicControl. These Controls can be reached from the indexed ActionControls property of the corresponding RibbonGroup. The index corresponds to the index of the ActionClientItem which can be selected in the Form designer. As long as the VCL ribbon is used I cannot see what may be wrong with my answer.

Comment: I down-voted because knowing how to invoke the ClientToScreen method of the TControl is useless if you can't or don't know how to address that Control. I'll be happy to remove the down vote if you just edit your answer.

Comment: @Peter Question asks for position given a control

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I don't understand your point. I know that the Question is asking for the position of a given control, ButtonOnRibbon.ClientToScreen is all fine if you can actually reference that ButtonOnRibbon Control, he explained how to do that in the comments but his original answer didn't explain how to actually get to the point where you can call ButtonOnRibbon.ClientToScreen(0, 0)

Comment: @Peter It's question and answer here. Question is how to get position given control.

Comment: @PeterVonča, besides my original answer used invalid params for ClientToScreen, I changed it to ClientOrigin and added an example how to access the actual control.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, when ribbon usage requires MS license it mean control have to use MS's code